# Where is the tomb of Erwin Rommel located?

Tags: world-war-two, military, 20th-century, erwin-rommel

On a Facebook page, I saw the following picture of Erwin Rommel's tomb and I'm wondering where it is.

[image: Erwin Rommel's tomb]

Maybe it was destroyed like many Nazi-era monuments and symbols, but maybe it's still standing.

I'm reading the biography of Rommel and seeing this and thinking that it might have been destroyed by the Allies really bothers me.

Comment: [VtC Trivial - google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Where+is+the+tomb+of+Erwin+Rommel+located%3F&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS581US581&oq=Where+is+the+tomb+of+Erwin+Rommel+located%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be Erwin Rommels grave in "Herrlingen, Deutschland" (Town of Herrlingen, Germany).

There is a video of it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PP-4hOWOFE).

The [local newspaper reported](http://www.swp.de/ulm/lokales/alb_donau/Gedenkfeier-in-Herrlingen-zu-Rommels-70-Todestag;art1158552,2854275) on the ceremony of the 70th anniversary of his death in late 2014, so it seems it's fine and undamaged.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a "Tomb." Ulysses S. Grant has a Tomb if anyone is looking for a primer. Interestingly Charles De Gaulle is buried in a simple grave though too. Next to his wife. There is "The De Gaulle nuclear powered Aircraft Carrier" though.